# Function not running correctly

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

I'm making a python 2.7 text-based RPG and my function for fighting isn't running properly. Here's my code:

```
def attack(self):
    print "A %r appears! It wants to fight!" % (self.name)
    while (player.health > 0) or (self.health > 0):
        player.health = player.health - ( ( randint(0,5) ) +  attack_multiplier(self.level) )
        print "%r strikes! Your health is down to %r" %(self.name, player.health)
        try:
            player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower)
            if (player.inventory.get(player.weapon) > 0) and (player.health > 0) and (self.health > 0):
                if weapon_probability() == "critical hit":
                    self.health = self.health - (((randint(0,5))) +  (attack_multiplier(weapon_levels.get(player.weapon))) * 2)
                    print "Critical Hit!"
                elif weapon_probability() == "hit":
                    self.health = self.health - ((((randint(0,5))) +  (attack_multiplier(weapon_levels.get(player.weapon)))))
                    print "Hit!"
                elif weapon_probability() == "miss":
                    self.health = self.health
                    print "Miss"
                print "Enemy health down to %r!" % (self.health)
            elif player.health <= 0:
                print "Your health...it’s falling"
                break
            elif self.health <= 0:
                print "Enemy vanquished!"
                break
        except ValueError:
            print "You don't have that"
```

What I see is:

```
'Bat' strikes! Your health is down to 95
What do you attack with? >>sword
'Bat' strikes! Your health is down to 91
What do you attack with? >>sword
'Bat' strikes! Your health is down to 87
What do you attack with? >>sword
'Bat' strikes! Your health is down to 85
What do you attack with? >>sword
'Bat' strikes! Your health is down to 82
What do you attack with? >>
```

That just keeps repeating and `player.health` even keeps going down into the negatives. I can't find the error. This function is a method on a class, and `player` is an instance of another class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing a method, not the lowercased input string:

```
player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower)
```

because you did not actually *call* `str.lower()` there. You probably don't have the `str.lower` method stored in `player.inventory` so `player.inventory.get(player.weapon)` returns `None` instead.

Because in Python 2 almost everything can be ordered relative to other objects, the test:

```
 player.inventory.get(player.weapon) > 0
```

is then always `False`.

Calling the method should fix at least that issue:

```
player.weapon = raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower()
```

Rather than use `player.inventory.get()` (which returns a default and masks your problems, use `player.inventory[player.weapon]`. This'll throw a `KeyError` to show that the user doesn't have that weapon, so adjust your exception handler to catch it:

```
except KeyError:
    print "You don't have that"
```

Comment: OMG how did i not see that. I'm so sorry

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept the answer...its my first question

Comment: @frg100: not a problem! Some people have waited *years* with marking posts as accepted, a day hardly is *long* around here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
 player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower)
```

it should be:

```
 player.weapon = (raw_input("What do you attack with? >>").lower())
```

Otherwise you are storing the function, not the result. Python treats everything as an object

You might also have a problem here:

```
while (player.health > 0) or (self.health > 0):
```

Possibly it could be:

```
while (player.health > 0) *and (self.health > 0):
```

Comment: It was at the player.weapon line. I need an or at the other one because i want the loop to run until either me or my enemy is defeated

Answer (score -2):

```
while (player.health > 0) or (self.health > 0):
```

Probably, you need to replace this fragment with:

```
while (player.health > 0) and (self.health > 0):
```

Comment: Author write  
"That just keeps repeating and player.health even keeps going down into  the negatives"  and I suggested that the problem in this fragment.